# Overloaded function in classic asp JScript

Tags: function, asp-classic, overloading, javascript

Is it possible to have an overloaded function in classic asp JScript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The last function will overwrite/replace the functions with the same name defined before it.

Read [How does Classic ASP (vbscript) handel duplicate Function names](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/ASP/Q_24076599.html)

Comment: Answer on the given link requires subscription. :(

Answer (score 6):

No.  The last definition of a function is the one that will be used.

For the best way to give your function added functionality in different contexts, try using one of the techniques described in [Function overloading in Javascript - Best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456177/function-overloading-in-javascript-best-practices), or perhaps [this technique mentioned by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-method-overloading/) might suit your purposes better.