# How can implement overloading in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, oop, dom-events

Im trying to call functions with same signature.

**Example:** There are two functions with same name:

```
<script>
    var obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,obj5;
    function OpenBox(obj1,obj2){
    // code
    }
    function OpenBox(obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,obj5){
    // code
    }
</script>
```

When I calling function on click event of  link

```
<a id='hlnk1' href='#' onclick='OpenBox(this,\"abhishek\"); return false;'> Open Box </a>
```

When I click on the above  link it is calling function **OpenBox(obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,obj5)**{}

It should be call function **OpenBox(obj1,obj2)**{} Instead.

What's going wrong in functions?

Comment: `'OpenBox(this,\"abhishek\") return false;'` should be `'OpenBox(this,"abhishek") return false;'`

Comment: Read the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456177/function-overloading-in-javascript-best-practices

Comment: @lbu - escaping the quotation marks, though not necessary in this case, doesn't actually hurt does it? I'd be more concerned that there's no semicolon between the closing bracket and the return.

Comment: I would just like to point out for people reading this question as part of a search that what Abhishek has described is called method overloading, *not* polymorphism. Polymorphism is the ability to adhere to specific interfaces or contracts. Javascript, being a duck-typed language, has implicit polymorphism baked in.

Comment: @Randolpho thanks for describe well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

mattn has the correct idea.  Because javascript has no typing those functions are equivalent.  What you could do is something like this:

```
function OpenBox_impl1(obj1,obj2){
    // code
}
function OpenBox_impl2(obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,obj5){
    // code
}

function OpenBox(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5) {
    if(arguments.length == 2)
        return OpenBox_impl1(obj1, obj2);
    else
        return OpenBox_impl2(obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,obj5);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

javascript can't define duplicate function in same scope. check [`arguments.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/functions_and_function_scope/arguments) are 2 or 5.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot overload functions in JavaScript. Instead, the most recently defined version of the function will be used, which is why in your case the version with 5 parameters is called (the final 3 are just `undefined`).

There are several ways around this, one if which is shown in Mikola's answer. An alternative is to pass in an object, and then check the contents of that object in the function (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456177/function-overloading-in-javascript-best-practices)):

```
function foo(a, b, opts) {

}

foo(1, 2, {"method":"add"});
foo(3, 4, {"test":"equals", "bar":"tree"});
```

Another option is to check `arguments.length`:

```
function foo(a, b) {
    if(arguments.length > 2) {
        var arg3 = arguments[3];
        //etc...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in the polymorphism  you can use a different signature method ,in javascript we can simulate polymorphism checking the type of the function parameter and execute certain task.

```
var input = document.getElementById('data');
polymorphism(input);
polymorphism('Hello word 2');
polymorphism('hello word 3', 5);

function polymorphism(arg,arg1){ 
  var string = null;
  var sqr = 0;
  if(typeof arg === 'string'){
    string = 'arg type String: \n'+arg;
  }else if (arg.tagName && arg.tagName === 'INPUT'){
    string = 'arg type Input: \n'+arg.value;
  }
  if(arg1 && typeof arg1 === 'number'){
    sqr = arg1*arg1;
    alert(string + ' and sqr = '+sqr);
  }else {
    alert(string);
  }    
}
```

Check this example in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yonatanalexis22/sx06sk78/)

Answer (score 2):

@abshik ,

There is nothing like that which is similar to c# or java. Javasccript behaves this way

```
function Test(arg1 ,arg2 , arg3, arg4)
{

}
```

when you are calling this function you can call in the following ways

```
Test(arg1);
Test(arg1,arg2);
Test(arg1,arg2,arg3);
Test(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4);
```

But sequence matters , so you can the function in the above ways.

Comment: You can also call it with no arguments or 5+ arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are trying to overload a function but that is not supported by Javascript. I think your best option is to use Polymorphism instead. View this article for more details: http://www.cyberminds.co.uk/blog/articles/polymorphism-in-javascript.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Once a function is defined in ecmascript, that name is locked. However, you can pass any number of parameters to that function so you do the rest of the work on the inside.

```
function foo(arg1, arg2) {
    // any code that is needed regardless of param count

    if(arg2 !== undefined) {
        // run function with both arguments
        console.log(arguments);
    } else if(arg1 !== undefined) {
        // run function with one argument
    } else {
        // run function with no arguments
    }
}

foo(1);
foo(1,2);
foo(1,2,3);
```

***Interesting note:*** you can pass in extra parameters that aren't in the function declaration. Do a `console.log` of `arguments` and you'll see everything in there. `arguments` is an `object` which can be accessed like / typecasted to an `array`.

Comment: yes Jackson right..  can I access all the parameter by arguments objects?