# Can you reset function input order efficiently?

Tags: javascript, function

Here is the idea: I want to be able to make it so that I can change the order in which inputs matter in a function. Lets say that the normal function looks as such:

```
var f = function(a,b,c,d){
    return a * b / c + d;
}
```

I want to be able to redefine the function, so that when a user calls `f(w,x,y,z)` if a variable(lets say `changed`) is true, it acts as if the user called `f(w,z,y,x)`! (not specifically in reverse order, just a different order than original function)

If I wanted to write a separate function that acted that way I could do the following:

```
var newF = function(a,b,c,d){
    if(changed === true){
        return f(c,d,b,a);
    }
    else{
        return f(a,b,c,d);
    }
}
```

and then replace all `f` calls with `newF` calls, but that is not what I am asking.

Is it possible to redefine a function with the same name as the actual function, and how that would be done? If I cannot, please explain why not.

## Explanation:

The reason I want to do this is because I have an app that has a function to make everything naturally sound (like points in a line being straight), but if I switch some of the values, it creates a fun, unrealistic, situation, which I thought would be a fun option to implement. My option above is doable, and I could use it, but I was just wondering if it is possible to keep it within the same function name

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you would want to do this.  What do you hope to accomplish by changing the order of arguments on the fly like this?

Comment: Is this necessary? having a concrete function behave differently based on the value of a disconnected variable sounds like a recipe for disaster

Comment: Maybe instead of accepting multiple arguments, you want the function to accept one object where each property is an argument. Then the caller does not have to worry about order.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve by doing this, because I'm pretty sure this is a terrible idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464386/how-can-implement-polymorphism-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: You can backup the old function then redefine it.  `var _oldF = f; var f = function(){  // call _oldF }`.

Comment: Can you change the original function `f`? Or is the idea to not do that?

Comment: I edited my answer to explain what prompted me to ask this.

Comment: Well you can do the if in the `f` function, and there mix the values to the right order.

Comment: this is a general question that I would like to work across the board...with complicated functions that manipulate the inputs, that would be double the necessary lines of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var oldF = f;

f = function( ... ){
    // do stuff
    oldF(...);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to redefine a function with the same name as the actual function, and how that would be done?

Yes, you can just assign to its identifier again:

```
f = function(a,b,c,d) {
    if (changed)
        return a * d / c + b;
    else
        return a * b / c + d;
};
```

If you need to call the actual function because you don't know its contents exactly (but want to intercept its parameters), you can do

```
f = (function(oldF) {
    return function(a,b,c,d){
        if (changed)
            return oldF(c,d,b,a);
        else
            return oldF(a,b,c,d);
    };
})(f);
```

Comment: it is a self-invoking function

Comment: To emphasize that it's an immediately-invoked function expression. They're [not necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17332911/1048572) actually.

Answer (score 1):

Use a factory method that returns the correct function at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Okay first, as long as you have defined a function like this :

```
var f = function(...){...};
```

then you can override it easily. But when you do this :

```
function f(...){...}
```

The explanation simply put, when you declare the function with `function f(...){...` the compiler will first look for every declared function that way then run your code. On the other hand declaring as a variable f will store the function during runtime not during the preprocessing.
Hence declaring like this :

```
function f(){
    console.log('a');
};
f();
function f(){
    console.log('b');
}

f();
```

Will output `b b`, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mmsU/)
While like this :

```
var f = function () {
    console.log('a');
};
f();
f = function () {
    console.log('b');
}

f();
```

Will output `a b`, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mceKZ/)

Now, I never put the arguments inside the exemples because JS doesn't care of the type and arguments size. The best way imo is to do like this :

```
var myProject = {};

myProject.fn = {

    f: function(args,options){
        //in your case while you need a,b,c,d you can use the args array to store them
        //options to define the 'changed' thing or whatever you need
        }

}
```

Comment: Um, but he has no function declaration? Btw, your second snippet does output `a b` not `a a`

Answer (score 0):

Aside from "why would you want to", you could do something like this:

```
var changed = false;

var f = function(a,b) {
    console.log("original function: " + a + "," + b);
}

f = (function(original) {
    return function(a,b) {
        console.log("new function");
         if (changed) {
             console.log("order changed");
             original(b,a);
         }
         else {
              original(a,b);
         }
     }
})(f);

f(1,2);
changed = true;
f(1,2);
```

Will output (in the console):

```
new function 
original function: 1,2 
new function 
order changed 
original function: 2,1
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfFWW/)