# Flot defining the X, Y series in an array

Tags: jquery, flot

New to javascript here - using Flot/Jquery: 
I am looking to store additional information to be displayed for hovering over points in the data array. i.e. data[i] = [x, y, 'additional info'] or [[x, y], 'additional info'] -

The Flot documentation only has this to say: 
The raw data format is an array of points: [ [x1, y1], [x2, y2], ... ]

How is it possible to specify which columns to use for X and Y as in
y = data[i][1], x = data[i][0] ?

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430371/how-to-create-new-property-and-value-for-a-function

Comment: I'm manipulating the data in python and then writing it to file as Json data for Javascript to handle, I'd prefer not to make an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You could create another array with the additional information you want to display and use the item index for displaying it in the tool tip.

```
showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, x + " "+ info[item.dataIndex]);
```

example - http://jsfiddle.net/Rnusy/65/

Comment: I thought of this - but it seems like a very Hackish solution. It means you have to write your data to two separate files or as two separate dict entries, and then your hover-over indexes both of them to find where the matching addinfo is (if the number of items do not match).