# Javascript (element, options) pattern

Tags: javascript, winjs

I see the below pattern used in JavaScript often.

```
function (element, options) {
}
```

Is there a specific name for this pattern?
I am looking for advice to use this pattern more efficiently.
As of now i am writing code in WinJS but, i have seen this being used on the web as well.

Comment: You might want to read [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466817/javascript-configuration-pattern)

Answer (score 3):

Using an `options` parameter in JavaScript is a common pattern, commonly known as the [*Configuration Object Pattern*](https://www.google.com/search?q=configuration%20object%20pattern%20javascript&oq=configuration%20object%20pattern%20javascript). It's basically an object literal that provides defaults to configure the behavior of the function/object in question. However, the first paramter in your example, `element`, appears to be nothing more than a context element that will be acted upon by said method.