# JavaScript overloading with a callback

Tags: javascript, callback, overloading

Following the pattern recommended in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456177/function-overloading-in-javascript-best-practices), where we have something akin to:

```
function foo(a, b, opts) {

}

foo(1, 2, {"method":"add"});
foo(3, 4, {"test":"equals", "bar":"tree"});
```

How would one then include a callback as the final parameter? I have function `foo()` that should be able to handle both of:

```
foo(x, y, function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

And

```
foo(x, y, z, function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading or misunderstanding but are you asking if you can put a function within an object?

Comment: That would work too, but can't find if that is possible

Comment: It is indeed possible. `{"oscar" : function () { console.log("I live in a trashcan.") }}` So, assuming you named your object foo, foo.oscar would run the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with the following solution:

```
foo(args) {}

foo({"x":"add", "callback": function() {
  // do stuff
}});


foo({"x":"equals", "y":"tree", "callback": function() {
  // do stuff
}});
```

And then simply checking to see if the last arguments value is a function, ala @PaulP.R.O.'s solution above:

```
if((arguments.length > 1) && (typeof arguments[arguments.length - 1] === 'function')) {
  var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say just use the arguments object:

```
function foo(a, b) {
    // Do stuff


    // Done stuff


    var alength = arguments.length;

    // If more than 2 arguments and last argument is a function
    if(alength > 2 && typeof arguments[alength - 1] === 'function')
        arguments[alength - 1].call(this);
}
```

Comment: but why do you use window.arguments instead of the local arguments variable?

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to accept a variable number of arguments, followed by a callback as the last one? Something similar to how PHP's [`array_udiff`](http://php.net/array-udiff) works?

This is fairly simple:

```
function foo() {
    var args = [], l = arguments.length, i;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) args[i] = arguments[i];

    var callback = args.pop();
    // now you have your variable number of arguments as an array `args`
    // and your callback that was the last parameter.
}
```

Comment: Why exactly would you create an exact copy of arguments array by `for` loop and then pop the callback, instead of just using `arguments`?

Comment: Because `arguments` is an array-like object, not an actual array.

Comment: You could just use `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`

Comment: @evan.bovie Could, but not allowed in older browsers ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol and that's when we drop support or use a shim.

Comment: @evan.bovie And that is why I have a `for` loop ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You could do similar to [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). (unlike [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call))

```
function foo(args, cb) {}

foo(['a', 'b', 'c'], function() {} );
```

And if you need to, you could put them into variables using [`.shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift):

```
function foo(args, cb) {
    var a = args.shift(),
        b = args.shift();
    // and so on...
}
```