# passed variable becomes undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, parameters

I have 2 function that do that same thing.  One works and one doesn't.

```
function showHideRedrawAttendanceAvg(chart, dataType)
{
    $("#attendanceCount").addClass("hide");
    $("#attendanceAvg").removeClass("hide");
    redrawAttendance(chart, dataType);//Parameters are defined
}

function redrawAttendance(chart, dataType) //Parameters are passed and are defined
{
    //Some logic
}

//I tried change the parameter name several times to make sure it was unique
function showHideRedrawAttendanceCount(agagfadfg)
{
    $("#attendanceAvg").addClass("hide");
    $("#attendanceCount").removeClass("hide");
    redrawAttendanceTree(agagfadfg);//Parameter is defined
}

function redrawAttendanceTree(agagfadfg)//Parameter becomes undefined
{
    //Some logic
}
```

I have no idea why the two functions behave differently.  I even removed all of my javascript from the file and just left the showHideRedrawAttendanceCount and redrawAttendanceCount functions and it still did not work.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="#">Attendance Average</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#attendance" onclick="showHideRedrawAttendanceAvg(attendance, 'Weekly')">Weekly</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#attendance" onclick="showHideRedrawAttendanceAvg(attendance, 'Monthly')">Monthly</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#attendance" onclick="showHideRedrawAttendanceAvg(attendance, 'Quarterly')">Quarterly</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#attendance" onclick="showHideRedrawAttendanceAvg(attendance, 'Yearly')">Yearly</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="#">Attendance Total</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#attendance" onclick="">Weekly</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#attendance" onclick="showHideRedrawAttendanceCount('Monthly')">Monthly</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#attendance" onclick="showHideRedrawAttendanceCount('Quarterly')">Quarterly</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#attendance" onclick="showHideRedrawAttendanceCount('Yearly')">Yearly</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: show your html code as well

Comment: redrawAttendanceTree/drawAttendanceTree are different names, is it a typo in the example code?

Comment: You create a function `function drawAttendanceTree(` but you call `redrawAttendanceTree`

Comment: Otherwise, try to add `redrawAttendanceTree` definition **before** calls.

Comment: By the way, the jQuery methods `.hide()` and `.show()` might be easier to use than `addClass("hide")` and `removeClass("hide")`.

Comment: Not very clear explanation of the problem.

Comment: So I didn't change any code, but the parameter is no longer undefined.  It wouldn't be the strangest thing I've seen today with javascript/html.

Answer (score 1):

When you call

```
redrawAttendanceTree(agagfadfg);
```

The `redrawAttendanceTree` function is not defined in the code sample you gave, so it will error saying that you're trying to call a function that doesn't exist.

`drawAttendanceTree` is never called in the code sample you gave.

Answer (score 0):

Function overloading in Javascript doesn't work as in other languages. In Javascript just because you have a parameter less in a function doesn't mean it has a different signature, instead it's the name that counts.

This way

```
function showHideRedrawAttendanceCount(agagfadfg)
```

will never get called.

To still achieve what you're trying, try out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456177/function-overloading-in-javascript-best-practices) on how to best overload functions in Javascript.