# Function parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is simple JavaScript question

I have a function that takes two parameters:

```
function myFunction(par1, par2) {

    //Part One
    //This will get executed always

    //Lots of logic here

    if (!par2) {


        //Part Two
        //this will not get executed if FALSE is passed as a second argument
        //more logic here

    }

}
```

In that function I have if, and its execution depends on par2 (which is bool)

That function is called many times in the code from other places, and when its called, both parts are executed. That is intended. Now, I need to use the same function, but I need only part one executed. So I figured to add second parameter as Bool type. And it works.

So for example, calling function like: myFunction (par1) will execute both parts. But, if I I call it like `myFunction (par1, true)` it will execute only Part 1.

That works.

I know that Javascript is not doing parameter checking, and I end up with undefined as a second parameter in certain occasions.

My question is this normal practice?

Comment: looks hackish but whatever works for you man :)

Answer (score 2):

You can have a default argument like this:

```
function myFunction (par1, par2) {
    par2 = typeof par2 !== 'undefined' ? par2 : false;

    ...
}
```

If you call the function without the second argument, it will safely default to `false` instead of `undefined`.

If you find that you need lots of arguments, and not all of them are required you can take an object as the agument instead. This gives you a greater degree of flexibility because you can choose to omit arguments without worrying about the order:

```
function myFunction (params) {
    var defaults = {
        par1 : 'a',
        par2 : false
    }

    if(typeof params == 'undefined') params = {};
    for(var prop in defaults){
        params[prop] = typeof params[prop] == 'undefined' ? defaults[prop] : params[prop];
    }

    // you can now assume that all of the properties are set in params
    // they will either be the value passed, or the default
}
```

The call could look like:

```
myFunction({
    par1 : 'a',
    par2 : 'b'
});
```

Or any other combination:

```
myFunction({
    par1 : 'a'
});
```

Even omit everything:

```
myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is normal as in it will WORK, however its harder to maintain and follow..

The parameters of a function call are the function's arguments.
Arguments are passed to functions by value. 
If the function changes the value of an argument, this change is not reflected globally or in the calling function.

However, object references are values, too, and they are special: if the function changes the referred object's properties, that change is visible outside the function..

Here is a wealth of info for you : [REF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

Answer (score 0):

> I know that Javascript is not doing parameter checking, and I end up with undefined as a second parameter in certain occasions.

`undefined` will act as if you passed `false`, because it's a falsy value. Nothing wrong with using that.

> Is this normal practice?

Yes, definitely, see also [Function overloading in Javascript - Best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/456177/1048572). Though instead of explicitly passing `false` you usually would just omit the argument.