# Javascript pass array to another function

Tags: javascript, arrays, overloading

Since overloading a function is not allowed, I am trying to find a way to pass values to a function.

In **php** I resolve in the following way:

```
// value2 and value3 are optional
function myMethod(value1, value2 = '', value3 = '')
{
   // TO DO
}
```

In **Java** I can overload the methods:

```
function myMethod(value1)
{
   // TO DO
}

function myMethod(value1, value2)
{
   // TO DO
}
```

In **javascript** I don't know:

```
var myAwesomeOptions =
{
   'value1' : 'abc',
   'value3' : 'def'
}

myMethod(myAwesomeOptions);    

function myMethod(options)
{
   if (value1 == ???? ) ...
   or

   switch(options)
   ....
}
```

As you can see I am trying to do an overload for a function. How can I pass values to a functions with optional parameters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function overloading in Javascript - Best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456177/function-overloading-in-javascript-best-practices)

Comment: It's not a complete answer, because I don't know how to switch between values. I know how to pass an array, but how to handle them?

Answer (score 2):

[Chech this link..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/javascript-check-if-object-is-array)

`Object.prototype.toString.call(vArg) === "[object Array]";`

Answer (score 0):

There's Argument object in JavaScript. For example.

```
function testme()
{
    var first_name=arguments[0] || "John";
    var last_name=arguments[1] || "Doe";
    alert(first_name);
    alert(last_name);
}

testme();

testme("Jane");
```

So you can use the Argument object to overload functions. Of course you can also pass array or collections too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in the following way:

```
function myMethod() {
 switch (arguments.length) {
  case 0:
   //TO DO
   break;
  case 1:
   var value1 = arguments[0];
   //TO DO
   break;
 }
}
```