# Function overloading in javascript to have two functions same name but diffrent input numbers

Tags: javascript

In a javascript.js file I am defining my functions where I would like to have to different definitions of same function for different function signature. In other words, is is possible in JavaScript:

```
1//
function foo(a, b){
  return a+b;
} 

2//
function foo(a){
  var b=10;// giving default value to variable b and not proving its value as input 
return a+b;
}
```

in a way I am trying to give a defualt value of 10 to local variable b if we want to call foo in the form foo(a) (no b given). So can we have form 1 and 2 for definition of foo in same javascript file?

Comment: Doesn't have it, already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456177/function-overloading-in-javascript-best-practices

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function foo(a, b){
  b = b || 10;
  return a+b;
}
```

if no value is passed for b, the first line will assign 10 to b, if it is passed, b will just be equated to b and you can use the value that was passed in.

The only thing you need to be careful with are "falsy" values such as 0

Comment: What do you mean by"The only thing you need to be careful with are "falsy" values such as 0"?

Comment: If you were to pass in 0, it would evaluate to false and b would be assigned 10. If you need that case, you'll have to do an explicit check for undefined: `if(typeof b == "undefined") { ... `

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two functions with the same name in javascript.  Whichever is defined last will take precedence.

You can, however, test arguments at run-time and change your behavior depending upon what was passed to the function.  This is a common design pattern and is used a lot by libraries like jQuery.

For example, in jQuery, there's a function `.animate()` which takes 1-4 arguments passed in a couple different ways:

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
.animate( properties, options )
```

Only the properties argument is required.  All the other arguments are optional and jQuery tests for their existence by checking to see what was passed and what type it was and figures out which form you are using and which arguments are present.

Or, another example:

```
.toggle( [duration ] [, complete ] )
.toggle( options )
.toggle( duration [, easing ] [, complete ] )
.toggle( showOrHide )
```

All of these forms are implemented with the same function using run-time checking of argument types and existence.  Here's an idea how you could implement the four forms of `.toggle()`.

```
function toggle(duration, easing, complete) {
    if (typeof duration === "boolean") {
        // toggle(bool) form 
        //   and the showOrHide arg is in the duration argument

    } else if (typeof duration === "object") {
        // toggle(options) form
        //   and the options object is in the duration argument

    } else {
        // toggle(duration, complete)
        // toggle(duration, easing, complete)
        // if no 3rd arg, then easing must have been left out
        if (!complete) {
            // completion function is in the 2nd arg to move it
            // to the proper named arg
            complete = easing
            // easing wasn't passed, give it a default value
            easing = "linear";
        }
        // process it as toggle(duration, easing, complete)
        // here

    }
}
```