# Javascript input timeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I've got a number of text boxes (dozens) that need to fire events when the user changes values. My users have requested not to have a commit button, and they don't want to have to activate a different control for the event to fire. So far as I understand it, that means I'm limited to running my method in the `oninput` event. My problem is I don't want to run the method with every key stroke-- I want to wait for some amount of time before assuming the user is done typing before commiting the change. For instance, one of the input boxes is looking for a number. If the user keys in '120' I don't want the method to fire once for '1', again for '12' then finally a third time for '120'.

Currently I have a function that uses setTimeout to delay the response for a second for the user to finish inputting info. If the user enters another character within this one second window the countdown starts over.

```
function CombineTextEntries(ctrl, FunctionObj){
    // This function prevents a text box from updating the Layout until the UpdateDelay time has been reached

    if (typeof(this.UpdateDelayTimeout) !== "undefined"){
        window.clearTimeout(this.UpdateDelayTimeout);
    }

    this.UpdateDelayTimeout = setTimeout( function(){FunctionObj();}, 1000);
}
```

I call this by setting the oninput attribute of the html to

```
oninput="CombineTextEntriesWithArg(this, MyFunction)"
```

The problem I am running into is some functions require one or more arguments. I can create a different function handler such as

```
function CombineTextEntriesWithArg(ctrl, FunctionObj, Arg){
    if (typeof(this.UpdateDelayTimeout) !== "undefined"){
        window.clearTimeout(this.UpdateDelayTimeout);
    }

    this.UpdateDelayTimeout = setTimeout( function(){FunctionObj(Arg);}, 1000);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
oninput="CombineTextEntriesWithArg(this, MyFunction, MyArg)"
```

but that seems rather kludgy. Can anyone propose a better solution? Is the best way by passing an object with the arguments enumerated within it [As specified in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456177/function-overloading-in-javascript-best-practices)? My only hesitation to this is I'd need to edit each of the functions I need to call to accept a single object which is kind of a pain.

Comment: to resume on what @Teemu said, you should hook the handler in code. You may use Function.bind() for that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to make it easier to pass arguments.

```
function CombineTextEntries(ctrl, fnc, args){

    if (ctrl.updateDelayTimeout ){
        window.clearTimeout(ctrl.updateDelayTimeout );
    }

    ctrl.updateDelayTimeout = setTimeout( function(){fnc.apply(this, args);}, 1000);
}
```

and call it

```
CombineTextEntries(this, yourFunctionName);
CombineTextEntries(this, yourFunctionName, [argument1]);
CombineTextEntries(this, yourFunctionName, [argument1, argument2]);
```