# Typed arrays in JavaScript are not arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var a = Int32Array(10);
console.log(Array.isArray(a)); // prints false to the console (Firefox)
```

Is there a reason why a typed JavaScript array is not an array or is this a bug that needs to be reported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) aren't arrays, it doesn't need reporting.

They're a very distinct set of objects with different functions. In the specification, they're [described](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-typedarray-objects) as objects which

> present an array-like view of an underlying binary data buffer

A good reason not to confuse them : they don't even offer the functions you have on arrays, for example `splice`.

It also doesn't follow the spec of `Array.isArray` as it's not an ["Array object"](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array-exotic-objects) as can be verified by setting the value at an out of range index using the bracket notation and checking the `length` isn't changed.

Comment: Well, in that case I can't use typed arrays as it would break my method of function overloading in some cases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456177/function-overloading-in-javascript-best-practices/29473331#29473331

Comment: Arrays and Typed Arrays can't be used indifferently. There's a very specific (and constraining) API for typed arrays.