# Function override in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, overriding

How to do function override in JavaScript ?

I have below code.

```
function helloWorld () {
    return 'helloworld ';
}

var origHelloWorld = window.helloWorld;

window.helloWorld = function() {
    return 'helloworld2';
}

alert(helloWorld);
```

I would like to get output like

`helloworld helloworld2`

What should I do ?

May be I described less. Actually I would like to call function the `helloworld` and I would like to get output of both functions jointly.

Comment: Call the original from your override and append the result to the return value.

Comment: And also call the overridden in alert's argument.

Comment: You must read about prototypes in javascript, it'll probably help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function helloWorld () {
    return 'helloworld ';
}

var origHelloWorld = window.helloWorld;

window.helloWorld = function() {
    return origHelloWorld() + ' ' +'helloworld2';
}

alert( helloWorld() );
```

Comment: Thanks @colxi for your reply. Your reply is correct if I only would like to print  'helloworld helloworld2'. But this is an example. I would like to get output of both function jointly whatever code is exists inside the functions. Thanks

Comment: i don't understand, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, you understand override?

**yours sample with the same parma, how to override it?**

and javascript has not a method about the override, but you can override in other ways. you can follow [other questions in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456177/function-overloading-in-javascript-best-practices)

Answer (score 0):

Using closures to avoid polluting the global namespace:

```
function helloWorld () {
    return 'helloworld ';
}

helloWorld = (function() {
    var original = window.helloWorld;
    return function () {
    return original() + ' helloworld2';
}})();

alert(helloWorld());
```