# Javascript calls wrong function

Tags: javascript

I got 2 functions in javascript (Chrome and IE):

```
function call(param1, param2){
   console.log("call param - 2");
}
```

and

```
function call(param1){
   console.log("call param - 1");
}
```

I called like this:

```
call(1,2);
```

But I receive this on console:

```
call - param - 1
```

Comment: how should javascript know which one you mean?  oh, c++/c#/java background is it

Comment: AFAIK you can't use function overloading in JavaScript. The function you created last is the one that is called. (if you switch the function declarations, your outcome will be "call param - 2". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456177/function-overloading-in-javascript-best-practices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called `function overloading`. Unfortunately, it's not available in JavaScript.

But you can always try to kind of simulate it if you need.

Please check this link where there's a discussion about the best way to do it:

[Function overloading in Javascript - Best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456177/function-overloading-in-javascript-best-practices)

Answer (score 2):

There is no function overloading in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arguments`.

```js
function call(){
   console.log("call param - " + arguments.length);
}

call(1);

call(1,2);

call(1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to use a single function with conditions inside.

```
function call(param1, param2){
  if(param2){
    console.log("call param - 2");
  } else if(param1) {
    console.log("call param - 1");
  } else {
    console.log("call invalid");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to overload your 'call' function. Javascript does not support function overloading.

A solution could be to make to seperate functions, with different names for each usecase.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, js do not check argument count : **you can call any function with any amount of arguments.**

Secondly, declaring a function means the same thing as declaring , so for a js engine, your code is

```
var call = fun1
var call = fun2
```

is the same as

```
var call
......
call = fun1
call = fun2
```

For function definitions, the value will also be hoisted, so it is actually

```
var call = fun2
......
```

so, **it will always be the later one.**

If you want to access all arguments in a normal function, you can use `arguments`, or do this

```
function f(foo, bar, ...args) {...}
```

in arrow function there is no `arguments`

Answer (score 0):

If `call(param1)` is defined after `call(param1, param2)` if is reassigned to `call` reference. So when you call `call(1,2)`,  `call(param1)` is invoked. There is no such thing as function overloading in JS. YOu can either utilise [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) to achive function that accpets variable arguments.