# How to call JavaScript function with same name but similar arguments

Tags: javascript, overloading

I have 2 JavaScript functions that are similar but one of them has a hardcoded variable while the other function's variable is to be defined when called upon. Sorry if what i am talking doesn't make sense but here is the code so you can understand it more easily:

```js
    function calculateCircumference()
    {
        var radius = 3;
        var circumference = Math.PI * 2 * radius;
        console.log("The circumference is " + circumference);
    }
    
    function calculateArea()
    {
        var radius = 3;
        var area = Math.PI * radius * radius;
        console.log("The area is " + area);
    }
    
    function calculateCircumference(radius)
    {
        var circumference = Math.PI * 2*radius;
        console.log("The circumference is " + circumference);
    }
    
    function calculateArea(radius)
    {
        var area = Math.PI * radius*radius;
        console.log("The area is " + area);
    }
    
    calculateCircumference();
    calculateArea();
    calculateCircumference(5);
    calculateArea(9);
```

**Output:**

```
The circumference is NaN
The area is NaN
The circumference is 31.41592653589793
The area is 254.46900494077323
```

I understand that if i change the function name of the second `calculateCircumference` and `calculateArea` , the whole code will work but what am i doing wrong that is showing `NaN` in the output when both of the function names are the same?

Or is this whole thing just plain wrong and not possible?

Any help is much appreciated, thank you

Comment: When you re-use the function name, the original function goes away. A name can only be used for one purpose in any given scope.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456177/function-overloading-in-javascript-best-practices

Comment: It is called: IMPOSSIBLE........ There is no function overloading in JavaScript.... just have one method and when you redefine it, it just replaces the other one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initial question describes [function overloading](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computer_Programming/Function_overloading), however JavaScript doesn't support it (without hacks). Instead, what will solve your issue is default parameters which is possible.

Since **ES6** you can set default parameters directly in the function declaration:

```js
function calculateCircumference(radius=3) {
    var circumference = Math.PI * 2 * radius;
    console.log("The circumference is " + circumference);
}

calculateCircumference();
calculateCircumference(5);
```

**Output**:

```
The circumference is 18.84955592153876
The circumference is 31.41592653589793
```

For **pre-ES6** however, you need to check if the variable is set inside the function:

```js
    function calculateCircumference(radius) {
        radius = typeof radius !== 'undefined' ? radius : 3;
        var circumference = Math.PI * 2 * radius;
        console.log("The circumference is " + circumference);
    }

    calculateCircumference();
    calculateCircumference(5);
```

**Output**:

```
The circumference is 18.84955592153876
The circumference is 31.41592653589793
```

Answer (score 4):

use a default value

```
function calculateArea(radius = 3)
{
    var area = Math.PI * radius*radius;
    console.log("The area is " + area);
}
```

calling `calculateArea()` without arguments will default to using 3 as the radius